# Does ts-morph can return source file if it's not a .ts?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, ts-morph

I'm using the function `getModuleSpecifierSourceFile` from [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph) to get the file designated by the import. But I get `undefined` from `.vue` imports (`.ts` files working perfectly well).
Does ts-morph only handle typescript file imports ?

Here is the file from which I get the undefined source file :

```
import CellVue from './CellVue.vue';

export { CellVue };
```